# error: expected unqualified-id before string constant

Tags: c++

After some research, i still don't understand the problem.

Const.hpp :

```
#ifndef CONST_HPP
#define CONST_HPP

#include <QString>

    const QString   CONFFILENAME("dsibubble.ini"),
                    STRSEP(" | ");

    const int       MAXIMGWIDTH = 960;

#endif // CONST_HPP
```

TabDataBase.cpp :

```
#include "Const.hpp"
func() {

    QString abc = STRSEP;

}
```

The use of `STRSEP` generate an `expected unqualified-id before string constant` error.
Moreover i use `CONFFILENAME` in an other class and i have no error.

```
QString path = QString("..//") + CONFFILENAME;
```

EDIT: Error's detail :

```
In file included ..\TabDataBase.cpp: #include "Const.hpp"  
expected unqualified-id before string constant: Const.hpp : STRSEP(" | ");
```

Comment: Could you give us the line of the error please?

Comment: Any chance `STRSEP` is a `#define` somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried declaring STRSEP on an separate line by itself and see if that works?  Also it maybe worth deleting and retyping the whole line as a dodgy character may have crept in that looks like white space but isn't...

Comment: @Nikolai N Fetissov: You're so right... Sorry for this question. And thanks to all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you have defined STRSEP as a string literal somewhere like:

```
#define STRSEP "blahblah"
```

Because I compiled your snippet and it's fine, but adding a define like the previous one I get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

Try defining the two constants using two separate statements. It's the only thing that I can think of that might have an effect.