# Unqualified-id before string constant

Tags: c++, string, c-preprocessor

On compiling following code I get error "expected unqualified-id before string constant"

```
In file "Notification_Constants.h"

namespace NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS
{
    #define SERVICE_EMAIL "service@company.com"
}
```

In file SendEmail.cpp

```
#include "Notification_Constants.h"

void UserPreferences::get_senders_email(String &_email)
{
    _email = NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS::SERVICE_EMAIL;
}
```

If i assign like following it works properly, what is the reason for the compilation error.

```
_email = SERVICE_EMAIL;
```

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658527/error-expected-unqualified-id-before-string-constant) but the reason is not mentioned.

String class declaration with relevant methods

```
class String
{
public:

String();
String(const String& src);
String(const char *new_str);
String& operator=(const String& src);
String& operator=(const char *new_str);
};
```

Comment: SERVICE_EMAIL string is enclosed in double quotes, it was copy and paste mistake

Comment: We do not have enough information to correctly identify the problem. Please at least provide more information about your `String` type.

Comment: I added the quotes so others won't get confused.

Comment: @Lstor I have updated the question with declaration of method in class String only with relevant methods

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Are there any other errors? There shouldn't be an error according to the information you've provided so far.

Comment: @Lstor I get the error for line _email = SERVICE_EMAIL; In the link to similar question I have mentioned it is the same problem but no one answered the reason for the same

Comment: @Lstor one important point i missed is SERVICE_EMAIL is defined in another namespace, and I am accessing it as NAMESPACE::SERVICE_EMAIL.I updated the code accordingly, its error on myside as code is very complicated to copy and paste completely

Comment: Ah. That's crucial information. The solution is posted below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you should put quotation marks around the email address:

```
#define SERVICE_EMAIL "service@company.com"
```

Second, you should not use `#define` at all. Use a `const` variable instead:

```
const String SERVICE_EMAIL = "service@company.com";
```

`#define`s are type unsafe, have no scope and are generally evil.

Last, you may want to consider using `std::string` instead of your `String` class.

**Update**:

The problem is that the preprocessor `#define`s are nothing more than text substitutions. When the preprocessor is done, your compiler will see

```
_email = NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS::"service@company.com";
```

There is no string constant in that namespace. `SERVICE_EMAIL` is not an identifier of any kind - it is just an indication to the preprocessor to substitute any occurrence of `SERVICE_EMAIL` with `"service@company.com"`.

The solution is to remove the namespace qualifier:

```
_email = SERVICE_EMAIL;
```

**Better solution:**

If you do not have access to the `#define`, you should wrap it in a header file, if possible:

```
#include "Notification_Constants.h"

namespace NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS {
    const String REAL_SERVICE_EMAIL = SERVICE_EMAIL;
}
```

and then use `NOTIFICATION_CONSTANTS::REAL_SERVICE_EMAIL` instead, which has scope, is a type, is a proper member of the namespace, and so on.

Comment: sorry SERVICE_EMAIL string is enclosed in double quotes, it was copy and paste mistake. Problem is it is defined in other domain which I cannot modify, how can i construct a string object out of it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, I think since I don't know the `String` type, is that SERVICE_EMAIL should be a string literal:

```
#define SERVICE_EMAIL "service@company.com"
```

but then, it should fail even in the latter solution. Maybe your code snippet doesn't show the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define SERVICE_EMAIL "service@company.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of service@company.com?
I think you wish to use a string to store an email address.

Try:

```
 #define SERVICE_EMAIL "service@company.com"
```